# agGrid How should I handle different classes of Objects on setRowData() or applyTransaction()?

Tags: ag-grid

In my case I parse a block of text, which includes un-parsable lines:

```
#//--Some Comment
000001
000002
00003
```

and when I parse this data I end up with an Array:

```
data:["#//--Some Comment",{value=000001},{value=000002},{value=00003}]
```

now when I pass this data into the agGrid with a ColumnDef for `field:'value'`, the first row will be empty.

How should I have the Grid notice that `(typeof data[0] === 'string')` and have the row added be a `fullWidth`-row that renders the String (or some other customized row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the solution.

As per docs -

> To use fullWidth, you must:
>
> - Implement the `isFullWidthCell(rowNode)` callback, to tell the grid    which rows should be treated as fullWidth.
> - Provide a fullWidthCellRenderer, to tell the grid what cellRenderer    to use when doing fullWidth rendering.

You can preprocess your data before passing to ag grid such that it looks like this -

```
data:[{value="#//--Some Comment"},{value=000001},{value=000002},{value=00003}]
```

Then You can implement `isFullWidthCell` like -

```
    this.isFullWidthCell = function(rowNode) {
// make first row fullwidth if data is string, this is called for every row
      return rowNode.rowIndex === 0 && typeof rowNode.data.value === 'string';
    };
```

And then provide a `fullWidthCellRenderer`.

Similar to [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-full-width-rows/#example-simple-full-width) in the docs.

**Update**
Since preprocessing data is not an option. Here is the updated `isFullWidthCell`

```
this.isFullWidthCell = function(rowNode) {
  return typeof rowNode.data === 'string';
};
```

Comment: Preprocessing the data so that they all contain `value` kind of defeats the idea behind my question, but I think I can simply skip that and do: `switch(typeof rowNode.data){case 'string':return true;break;default:return false;break;}` right?... now off to research CellRenderers

Comment: @Erska I wasnt aware preprocessing ws not an option. Yes it should work fine the way you have it. Let me also update my answer.

Comment: @Erska updated answer to include typeof check of plain data without switch